# Dynamic WHERE Clause & SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

I need to create functionality for users to determine the WHERE criteria of a select - the criteria will be dynamic.

Is there a way I can achieve this without opening up my code to SQL injection?

I'm using C# / .NET Windows Application.

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: What is the technology you are using ? .net ? php ? ruby ? ... other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah two phases. Given you column names and operators are not direct user input. E.g. picked from a  list or radio group etc
then 
String WhereClause = String.Format("Where {0} {1} @{0}","Customer", "=");

So now you Have "Where Customer = @Customer".

Then you can add aparamer Customer and set it from the user input.

There are a few ways to attack this, depends on how complex your criteria could be though.

Comment: Yes, my column names and operators are picked from a list. My question now would be if this is possible with Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Using parameterized queries would go long way toward protecting you from SQL injection attacks, because most bad things happen in the value portion of your `where` conditions.

For exampleg given a condition `a=="hello" && b=="WORLD"`, do this:

```
select a,b,c,d
from table
where a=@pa and b=@pb -- this is generated dynamically
```

Then, bind `@pa="hello"` and `@pb="WORLD"`, and run your query.

In C#, you would start with an in-memory representation of your `where` clause in hand, go through it element-by-element, and produce two output objects:

- A string with the `where` clause, where constants are replaced by automatically generated parameter references `pa`, `pb`, and so on (use your favorite naming scheme for these blind parameters: the actual names do not matter)
- A dictionary of name-value pairs, where names correspond to the parameters that you've inserted in your `where` clause, and values that correspond to the constants that you pulled from the expression representation.

With these outputs in hand, you prepare your dynamic query using the string, add parameter values using the dictionary, and then execute the query against your RDBMS source.

**DO NOT DO THIS**

```
select a,b,c,d
from table
where a='hello' and b='WORLD' -- This dynamic query is ripe for an interjection attack
```

Comment: Right... so do you have any idea how I can use parameters when the fields and operators are dynamic?

Comment: Clarification - I know how to use parameters. The issue here is the parameters, parameter values and operators are dynamic. So I can't simply add parameters like I would usually do.

Comment: @Becky I just edited the answer to include general info on how to extract parameters from your query expression representation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. How would I go about this if I'm using Stored Procedures? Possible?

Comment: @Becky This depends a lot on how you use stored procedures. If the stored procedures are simply referenced from your dynamic SQL, or if the structure of their generated SQL is limited, you could continue using parameters (search for "Preventing SQL Injection Attacks in Stored Procedures" for info on how to do it). If the SQL you must generate is too heavy-weight for your SPs to handle, for example, because you would like to allow expressions of arbitrary structure and complexity, you would be better off not using SPs.

Comment: SPs are doable but not nice. Passing in variable length parameter lists and extracting them. Can't see any real technical befihnt to usiong them, execpt if you wanted to reuse them ina place you couldn't your .net code.